# html table header rowspan to center headers

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/g63xs/)**:

```
<table border="1">
<thead>        
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Items</th>
        <th colspan="2">Type</th>
        <th colspan="4">Values</th>
        <th colspan="2">Date</th>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th colspan="2">Before</th>
        <th colspan="2">After</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

In the header of the table, I would like to have the headers `Items`, `Type` and `Date` to be centered vertically. I tried using `rowspan="2"` on these headers, but that didn't work. Any idea please?

Comment: Contrary to the title, the sample code has no `rowspan`. The markup is malformed (does not comply with HTML table model), and the question in the body (about vertical placement) seems unrelated to the title, the sample code, and the attempt of using `rowspan`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `rowspan`, you have to *not add* the columns in the next rows (or as much rows as the *`rowspan` number minus one*).

Your **[demo, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/g63xs/1/)**:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Items</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
            <th colspan="4">Values</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Before</th>
            <th colspan="2">After</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Note: If you remove the `Before` and `After` `colspan`, your `Values` `colspan` can be just `2`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Oh, come on, really? I even closed the `</table>` for example's sake. Do you really think he is going to use an empty `tbody`!?  (By that reasoning, is this invalid html because there are no `html` or `body` tags as well!?)

Comment: “Table column 4 established by element th has no cells beginning in it.”, etc., says the W3C Validator when validating against HTML5, which formalizes the HTML table model.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela As I said, that's due to the empty `tbody`. Try this: `<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>6</td></tr></tbody>` and it'll probably be gone. With this `tbody` it is both HTML4 Strict and HTML5 valid. Without, it is invalid (in both).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
<thead>        
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Items</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Type</th>
        <th colspan="4">Values</th>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Date</th>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Before</th>
        <th colspan="2">After</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
<thead>        
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Items</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
        <th colspan="2">Values</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Date</th>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <th>Before</th>
        <th>After</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```